# How to call a class inside of an application - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a console application that creates CSV data when it is run. I want to move this app to another project as a class, and then call that class when a button is pressed. How would I do this?

The class I will move looks like this

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()

//content


}

 public class MyClass
//more content
}
```

and the button would look like this

```
//form data
<a class="button">Download CSV</a>
```

My controller has simple actions...

```
public IActionResult Index(){
    return View();
}

public IActionResult DownloadCSV(){
    //do I need something here?
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This `public class DownloadCSV(){` is not valid C# syntax since a class does not have parenthesis. They are only used for methods. Please add the code that you have in your controller.

Comment: Do you know how to reference other assemblies? Break this out into a Class Library (DLL) and reference it in both the console app and your other project.

Comment: "//do I need something here?" - yes: generate the CSV data and then [`return File(data, contentType, filename);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file) instead of `return View()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will try doing this and let you know later on today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option is to create this class as a **library**

-like this: [Build a C# Standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio)

Once your new library is created you need to [Reference it](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-add-references-your-visual-studio-project.cfm) from the other project where you want to use this **class**

Creating a class as a **library** will let you use it in any other project/application in the future.

So I would strongly recommend to keep your repetitive classes as libraries, such as *CSVManager class* or *ConnectionManager class* and any other **class** you might use more than once.